# Creating a nested object/modal from an existing nested object/modal in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I am using deeply nested model in my project (using simple_form and cocoon). Everything works fine as long as all nested objects are new.

My problem is, that I want to create a nested object from an existing (nested) object.

### Here is my model

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :submitter
    has_one :composition

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :submitter, :composition
end

class Submitter < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :spouse
    has_many :children
    has_many :receipts
    has_many :applications

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :spouse, :children, :receipts, :applications
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :submitter
    has_many :receipts
end
```

The working process looks like this:

> new Application --> new Submitter --> new Child

All can be created using one form.

Additionally, I also want to implement the following process:

> new Application --> **existing** Submitter --> new Child

The existing object should be chosen by a dropdown list box.

### Here is the (simplified, working) code of the view:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@application)  do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :submitter do |submitter| %>  
        <%= render "submitter_fields", :f => submitter %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_submitter_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.input :firstname %>
<%= f.input :lastname %>
<%= render "child", :f => f %>
```

**_child.html.erb**

```
<div id="childs">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :children do |child| %>
      <%= render "child_fields", :f => child %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add child', f, :children %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_child_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove child", f %>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a dropdown list which is populated with all existing Submitters. For example:

```
<%= f.assosciation :submitter %>
```

And here starts my problem: To build the form for adding a new child to the selected submitter, I need to assign this object to the form builder. I have no idea how to do this.

Can somebody give me a hint how to implement this? Or is this scenario simply not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple_fields_for takes a second argument the object: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb#L33 maybe if you pass your existing submitter it will work.

Comment: not only that, you can use, simple_fields_for as fields_for, it's supposed to work the same: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: Thanks @ChuckE, I think you directed me into the right way.

I extended the the new.html.form like this: 

    `<%= simple_form_for(@application)  do |f| %>`
    `<%= f.assosciation :submitter %>`
    `<%= f.simple_fields_for :submitter, <Submitter Object> do |submitter| %>`  
        `<%= render "submitter_fields", :f => submitter %>`
    `<% end %>`
    `<% end %>`

The only question left is how to dynamically get the object from f.association and assign it the simple_fields_for (<Submitter Object> block. Doing it manually already work like a charme! Thanks!

Comment: according to the fields_for documentation, you have to do it yourself, i guess. One way of doing it is initializing the association when it doesn't exist yet. So, in controller:  `@application.build_submitter unless @application.submitter.present?` and then in the view: `f.simple_fields_for @application.submitter...` but maybe you'll get more info about it in the [simple form google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum)/plataformatec-simpleform

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, @ChuckE. But your suggestion is too "static"... I would need to know in advance which Submitter should be "selected" (in controller), but I want to do this dynamically in the view through the dropdown list box (`f.assosciation :submitter`). Any further ideas? Or is this scenario simply impossible to handle in that way? Thanks!

Comment: it is indeed an ugly solution. If you were using fields_for it would have worked actually, according to the documentation... maybe ask in simple form forum why your implementation is not working, and until then, use the one i suggested you in the first place?

Comment: Thanks @ChuckE. I decided to refactor my application. I added an authentification solution to get the submitter object when entering the discussed view. If no user is logged in, a new submitter will be created. Thanks again for your kind help!